# About blowing up $\mathbb{V}({x^2+y^2-z^2})$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Following is the photo taken from page 112 of the book *An Invitation to Algebraic Geometry.*

[image]

The author is blowing up $\mathbb{V}(x^2+y^2+z^2)$ at the origin. My confusion is, when defining
$$
V=\pi^{-1}(\mathbb{V}(x^2+y^2-z^2))\cap(\mathbb{A}\times\mathbb{A}_z^2)
$$

Why aren't we restrict $z=1$? And where does the isomorphism
$$
\{((x,y,z),[x:y:z]) \;|\; x^2+y^2=z^2\}\cong \{(x,y,z,u,v) \;|\; x=uz,y=vz,u^2+v^2=1\}
$$
come from?

Answer (score 1):

You know that 
$$
\{((x,y,z),[x:y:z])\}\cong \mathbb{A}^3 \times \mathbb{P}^2
$$
and $\mathbb{P}^2$ is covered by three affine space $\mathbb{A}_x^2$, $\mathbb{A}_y^2$, $\mathbb{A}_z^2$.

When you intersect the preimage with $\mathbb{A}_z^2$, $\{([x:y:z])\}$ becomes $\{((\frac{x}{z},\frac{y}{z},1))\}$.

Then let $u=\frac{x}{z},v=\frac{y}{z}$, you'll get the result.